# Jaeger/Opentracing with Kafka and docker compose

Tags: apache-kafka, jaeger, opentracing

I can only find old and incomplete examples of using opentracing/jaeger with Kafka. I want to run an example locally as a proof of concept - opentracing spans to kafka.

I managed to get some of this working, but on `jeager-query` service I keep getting:

```json
"msg":"Failed to init storage factory","error":"kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)"
```

I'm not sure if I need to use some sort of storage i.e. cassandra too?

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
        - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
    ports:
        - 2181:2181

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    container_name: kafka
    environment:
        - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
        - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
        - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
        - KAFKA_LISTENERS-INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
        - KAFKA_ADVERTISED=INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
        - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
        - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
        - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=INTERNAL
    ports:
        - 9092:9092
    depends_on:
        - zookeeper
    restart: on-failure
  
  jaeger-collector:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-collector
    container_name: jaeger-collector
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    ports:
      - "14250:14250"
      # - "14267:14267"
      - "14268:14268" # HTTP collector port to receive spans
      - "14269:14269" # HTTP health check port
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
      SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE: "kafka"
      KAFKA_TOPIC: "somekafkatag"
      KAFKA_BROKERS: "kafka:9092"
      KAFKA_PRODUCER_BROKERS: "kafka:29092"

  jaeger-agent:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-agent
    container_name: jaeger-agent
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    command: ["--reporter.grpc.host-port=jaeger-collector:14250"]
    ports:
      - "5775:5775/udp"
      - "6831:6831/udp"
      - "6832:6832/udp"
      - "5778:5778"
    environment:
      LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
      SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE: "kafka"
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - jaeger-collector

  jaeger-ingester:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-ingester
    container_name: jaeger-ingester
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    ports:
      - "14270:14270" # HTTP health check port: http://localhost:14270/
      - "14271:14271" # Metrics port: http://localhost:14271/metrics
    restart: on-failure
    command: ["--kafka.producer.brokers=kafka:9092"]
    environment:
      LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
      INGESTER_PARALLELISM: "1"
      INGESTER_DEADLOCKINTERVAL: "0ms"
      SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE: "kafka"
      KAFKA_CONSUMER_BROKERS: "kafka:9092"
      METRICS_BACKEND: "expvar"
      KAFKA_BROKERS: "kafka:29092"

  jaeger-query:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-query
    container_name: jaeger-query
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    ports:
      - "16686:16686" # Jaeger UI port
      - "16687:16687" # HTTP health check port: http://localhost:16687/
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
      SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE: "kafka"
      KAFKA_CONSUMER_BROKERS: "kafka:9092"
      KAFKA_BROKERS: "kafka:29092"

networks:
  kafka-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing a lot of information. I managed to get it working:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
        ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    ports:
        - 2181:2181

  cassandra:
    hostname: cassandra
    image: cassandra
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    environment:
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE: 1G
      HEAP_NEWSIZE: 256M
    ports:
     - "9042:9042"

  cassandra-schema:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-cassandra-schema
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    depends_on:
      - cassandra

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    container_name: kafka
    environment:
        KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
        KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
        ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: "yes"
        KAFKA_LISTENERS-INTERNAL: //kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED: INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
        KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
        KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
        KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
    ports:
        - 9092:9092
        - 29092:29092
    depends_on:
        - zookeeper
    restart: on-failure
  
  jaeger-collector:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-collector
    container_name: jaeger-collector
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    ports:
      - "14250:14250"
      - "14267:14267"
      - "14268:14268" # HTTP collector port to receive spans
      - "14269:14269" # HTTP health check port
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
      SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE: "kafka"
      KAFKA_BROKERS: "kafka:9092"
      KAFKA_PRODUCER_BROKERS: "kafka:29092"

  jaeger-agent:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-agent
    container_name: jaeger-agent
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    command: ["--reporter.grpc.host-port=jaeger-collector:14250"]
    ports:
      - "5775:5775/udp"
      - "6831:6831/udp"
      - "6832:6832/udp"
      - "5778:5778"
    environment:
      LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
      SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE: "kafka"
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - jaeger-collector

  jaeger-ingester:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-ingester
    container_name: jaeger-ingester
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    ports:
      - "14270:14270" # HTTP health check port: http://localhost:14270/
      - "14271:14271" # Metrics port: http://localhost:14270/metrics
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      LOG_LEVEL: debug
      INGESTER_PARALLELISM: 1
      INGESTER_DEADLOCKINTERVAL: ms
      SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE: cassandra
      CASSANDRA_SERVERS: cassandra
      CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE: jaeger_v1_dc1
      METRICS_BACKEND: expvar
      KAFKA_CONSUMER_BROKERS: kafka:29092
      KAFKA_CONSUMER_TOPIC: jaeger-spans
    depends_on:
      - cassandra-schema

  jaeger-query:
    image: jaegertracing/jaeger-query
    container_name: jaeger-query
    networks:
      - kafka-net
    ports:
      - "16686:16686" # Jaeger UI port
      - "16687:16687" # HTTP health check port: http://localhost:16687/
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - cassandra-schema
    environment:
      LOG_LEVEL: debug
      SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE: cassandra
      CASSANDRA_SERVERS: cassandra
      CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE: jaeger_v1_dc1
      JAEGER_ENDPOINT: http://jaeger-collector:14268/api/traces

networks:
  kafka-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see that jaeger-query configuration includes: SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE: "kafka"

The error indicates that a kafka client used by jaeger-query to store spans in Kafka cannot in fact reach Kafka, and therefore the jaeger storage factory fails to initialize.

This can be either because Kafka failed to start (did you check)? Or a misconfig of the network in your docker.

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering. Yes, the kafka container is running fine, I double checked. Its weird, collector and and agent work fine, but ingester and query both fail

Answer (score 0):

Jaeger all in one with kafka   with tracing interceptors for kafka-connect

```
version: '3'

services:
  jaeger:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
    hostname: jaeger
    container_name: jaeger
    restart: always
    environment:
      - COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HTTP_PORT=9411
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=nextcloud
    ports:
      - 5775:5775/udp
      - 6831:6831/udp
      - 6832:6832/udp
      - 5778:5778 
      - 16686:16686
      - 14268:14268
      - 14250:14250
      - 9411:9411

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.1.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.1.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - jaeger
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.1.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081

  connect:
    image: cnfldemos/kafka-connect-datagen:0.4.0-6.1.0
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - jaeger
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/*
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "globaltracer.CustomProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "globaltracer.CustomConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components,/usr/share/java/kafka"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR
      JAEGER_SERVICE_NAME: kafka-connect
      JAEGER_AGENT_HOST: jaeger
      JAEGER_AGENT_PORT: 6831
      JAEGER_SAMPLER_TYPE: const
      JAEGER_SAMPLER_PARAM: 1
      JAEGER_REPORTER_LOG_SPANS: 'true'


  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:6.1.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://ksqldb-server:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://localhost:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021

  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:6.1.0
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksqldb-server
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 0
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      KSQL_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: "http://connect:8083"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'

  ksqldb-cli:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:6.1.0
    container_name: ksqldb-cli
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true

  ksql-datagen:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-examples:6.1.0
    hostname: ksql-datagen
    container_name: ksql-datagen
    depends_on:
      - ksqldb-server
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
    command: "bash -c 'echo Waiting for Kafka to be ready... && \
                       cub kafka-ready -b broker:29092 1 40 && \
                       echo Waiting for Confluent Schema Registry to be ready... && \
                       cub sr-ready schema-registry 8081 40 && \
                       echo Waiting a few seconds for topic creation to finish... && \
                       sleep 11 && \
                       tail -f /dev/null'"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      STREAMS_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST: schema-registry
      STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT: 8081

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:6.1.0
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
```